# Imported function give a TypeError: ... is not a function

Tags: typescript

I have a function which I use in a lot of files. This works:

```
import moment from 'moment';

let monthAsString = (month: number): string => {
  return moment().locale('de').month(month - 1).format("MMMM");
}

configuration2005.push(
  {
    worksheetName: monthAsString(10),
  }
)
```

When separating the function in an extra file I get a TypeError:

```
export function monthAsString(month: number): string {
  return moment().locale('de').month(month - 1).format("MMMM");
}
```

```
import { monthAsString } from './configurations';

configuration2005.push(
  {
    worksheetName: monthAsString(10),
  }
)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: configurations_1.monthAsString is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mles/project/src/configuration-2005.ts:12:22)
    ...
```

What am I missing here? VSCode is not showing any error.

Comment: Working fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-thunder-3clws?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Did you resolve this by any chance?? My environment is causing this problem too..

Answer (score 0):

@Silvan Bregy: I resolved this by putting the function in the object:

```
configuration2005.push(
  {
    worksheetName: moment().locale('de').month(10 - 1).format("MMMM"),
  }
)
```

But as Rashomon commented: It should work with import/export too.